# React TinyMCE without Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am new to React and am trying to use the [React TinyMCE Component](https://github.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce) in my website.

I can get a basic React application up and running but when I attempt to integrate the TinyMCE component I receive an "Uncaught ReferenceError: TinyMCE is not defined" error in the console.

From what limited knowlegde I have it seems to be using the Node "requires" feature?  Is there any way of using the component without Node?

I have created [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/KA1zhoMldBEnlg9IVNvc) example in Plunker which shows the problem, removing the following line in the script.jsx file prevents the error:

```
            < TinyMCE content = "<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
  config = {
    {
      plugins: 'autolink link image lists print preview',
      toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright'
    }
  }
  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems. First `react-tinymce-min.js` isn't being found. So you need to somehow pull that into your project. The brain-dead way of doing that is to just copy the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/instructure-react/react-tinymce/master/dist/react-tinymce.js) into your project. Second since you aren't using Webpack `TinyMCE` gets put into the global variable `ReactTinymce`.  [Edited plunk.](https://plnkr.co/edit/MscAF0VxYLE2wlHSZjPQ?p=preview)

Ultimately you'll want to use Webpack. That's what all the cool kids use. And it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.  I'll look into Webpack, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody that has the same issue this is what I ended up with:

Ensure you have a file named .babelrc (including the .)

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Demo",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "PN",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "react": "^0.14.6",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.6",
    "react-tinymce": "^0.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "webpack": "^1.12.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: "babel",
            query:
      {
        presets:['react']
      }
        }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extension: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.es6']
    }
}
```